# Creating a groups structure in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, organic-groups

I'm starting developing a Web Site for a Sport Club. This site will have a "main" site with some "institutional" content, and every sport that is present in the club will have it's own micro-site.

For example, i'll have this sitemap.

Club

+++History

+++About

- Rugby (one random sport)

  - Blog
  - Photos
  - Videos
  - User Comments
  - etc.
- Hockey (another sport)

  - Blog
  - Photos
  - Videos
  - User Comments
  - etc.

So, which is the best way to make this work? I was thinking using Taxonomies and views.

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build out your site using views and arguments.

Add a CCK field (sport) or a taxonomy vocabulary (sport) and attach it to the blog, photo, video, etc.. content types.

When you build your views you would use the argument of sport in the path. That way you can have paths like:

- example.com/rugby/blogs
- example.com/hockey/blogs

The path to this example view would be %/blogs (% being replaced by the argument).

A couple videos on views and arguments:

- http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-arguments
- http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode39

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend on the [OpenAtrium](http://openatrium.com/) installation profile.
Define each sport as a ([og](http://drupal.org/project/og))group, add add to it whatever you need.

I believe that for your needs OpenAtrium fits nicely, and will save you lots of time.

Good Luck !
Shushu

Comment: THanks for your answer! But i don't think this can help me. This site needs to be in the www.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. OpenAtrium is just like any other Drupal site.

Comment: There is no reason why not to use open atrium for any site. The difference between intranet and internet sites is just the decision what to do with it. If you need to use its features - use it !

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend organic groups module as one group one sport. Open Atrium could be a good installation profile (it also uses organic groups) but it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you are asking this type of question, you should probably go with Open Atrium.  It is pretty much an intranet (and Organic Groups) right out of the box.  I have 5 installations of it running publicly (in the www). @Shushu is right, any website can be an intranet or internet, it just depends on if you expose it to the world, or just to your local intranet.  But if you are looking to dive into Drupal, use a drupal install with OG.  But it really depends on how much time and effort you want/can put into it.